# Zagg Folio Tab 4 no longer connects to my Galaxy Tab 3

Tags: updates, keyboard, bluetooth, samsung-galaxy-tab-3-10.1

I own a Galaxy Tab 3 10.1, and I just updated it to Android 4.4.2. I have a Zagg Folio Tab 4 10.1, and up until the update, it worked perfectly fine. Now, it connects to my tablet, but input does not work. I've cleared my cache and the Bluetooth cache, but neither have worked. Also, I have tried unpairing and re-pairing it. I also paired it to my Galaxy S4, which worked fine. I then re-paired it to my Tab 3, but that did not work either. What can I do to fix it?